# detecting a box using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to detect the following box dimensions using OpenCV. I also have the depth image if you find it useful.

What I have tried is to use hough transform and get the interesected points of the lines...

My question is, is it possible to get the contours then use hough transform on the selected contour ? How would the code looks like for that ?

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

cv::Point2f center( 0, 0 );

cv::Point2f computeIntersect( cv::Vec4i a,
  cv::Vec4i b )
{
  int x1 = a[0], y1 = a[1], x2 = a[2], y2 = a[3], x3 = b[0], y3 = b[1], x4 = b[2], y4 = b[3];
  float denom;

  if ( float d = ((float)(x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4)) - ((y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4)) )
  {
    cv::Point2f pt;
    pt.x = ((x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (x3 - x4) - (x1 - x2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)) / d;
    pt.y = ((x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)) / d;
    return pt;
  }
  else
    return cv::Point2f( -1, -1 );
}

void sortCorners( std::vector<cv::Point2f>& corners,
  cv::Point2f center )
{
  std::vector<cv::Point2f> top, bot;

  for ( int i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++ )
  {
    if ( corners[i].y < center.y )
      top.push_back( corners[i] );
    else
      bot.push_back( corners[i] );
  }
  corners.clear();

  if ( top.size() == 2 && bot.size() == 2 ) {
    cv::Point2f tl = top[0].x > top[1].x ? top[1] : top[0];
    cv::Point2f tr = top[0].x > top[1].x ? top[0] : top[1];
    cv::Point2f bl = bot[0].x > bot[1].x ? bot[1] : bot[0];
    cv::Point2f br = bot[0].x > bot[1].x ? bot[0] : bot[1];


    corners.push_back( tl );
    corners.push_back( tr );
    corners.push_back( br );
    corners.push_back( bl );
  }
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{


  Mat src, src_copy, edges, dst;
  src = imread( "freezeFrame__1508152029892.png", 0 );

  src_copy = src.clone();

  GaussianBlur( src, edges, Size( 5, 5 ), 1.5, 1.5 );

  erode( edges, edges, Mat() );// these lines may need to be optimized 
  dilate( edges, edges, Mat() );
  dilate( edges, edges, Mat() );
  erode( edges, edges, Mat() );

  Canny( edges, dst, 50, 300, 3 ); // canny parameters may need to be optimized 
  imshow( "canny", dst );

  vector<Point> selected_points;
  vector<vector<Point> > contours;
  findContours( dst, contours, RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );


  for ( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
  {
    Rect minRect = boundingRect( contours[i] );

    if ( (minRect.width > src.cols / 2) | (minRect.height > src.rows / 2) ) // this line also need to be optimized 
    {
      selected_points.insert( selected_points.end(), contours[i].begin(), contours[i].end() );

        drawContours( src, contours, i, Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ), 3 );

    }
  }

 imshow( "Selected contours", src );

 cv::waitKey( 0 );

  vector<Vec4i> lines;
  HoughLinesP( selected_points, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 50, 50, 10 );
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
  {

    cv::Vec4i v = lines[i];
    lines[i][0] = 0;
    lines[i][1] = ((float)v[1] - v[3]) / (v[0] - v[2]) * -v[0] + v[1];
    lines[i][2] = src.cols;
    lines[i][3] = ((float)v[1] - v[3]) / (v[0] - v[2]) * (src.cols - v[2]) + v[3];

    v = lines[i];
    cv::line( src, cv::Point( v[0], v[1] ), cv::Point( v[2], v[3] ), CV_RGB( 0, 255, 0 ) );

  }



  std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners;
  for ( int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
  {
    for ( int j = i + 1; j < lines.size(); j++ )
    {
      cv::Point2f pt = computeIntersect( lines[i], lines[j] );
      if ( pt.x >= 0 && pt.y >= 0 )
        corners.push_back( pt );
    }
  }

  for ( int i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++ )
  {
    // Draw corner points
    cv::circle( src, corners[i], 3, CV_RGB( 255, 0, 0 ), 2 );
  }

  imshow( "line src", src );
  imshow("line dest", edges );
  cv::waitKey( 0 );


  return 0;
}
```

[image]

I want to compute the volume of that box actually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a very broad question... I'll just give you some advice about how I would proceed, not code. I suppose you want to identify the volume of any box on a casual table, not just the box in this very specific image.

With a (supposedly) dense depth image you can reconstruct a 3D point cloud of the scene. You can use i.e. the [pcl library](http://pointclouds.org) and a fitting method like RANSAC or other to fit planes in the pointcloud.

You should then understand which surface is the table, and then find the box surfaces and compute the enclosed volume.

Another way could be finding corners in the image using cv::goodFeaturesToTrack(), compute the corresponding 3D points using again the depth image to compute just the 3D positions of the detected corners, then find the lines connecting the corners and trying to find out which lines are perpendicular to other lines.

Comment: how would I compute the corresponding 3D Points using the depth image ?

Comment: finding the lines connecting the corners is N! problem I guess, how would I optimize it ?